# SQuirrel - Prevent multiple result tabs

Tags: squirrel-sql

I am using SQuirrel SQL Client Version 3.5 and everytime I modify and run a query it opens up a new result tab. I would prefer that it re-use the existing result tab (replacing the contents) Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this (without having to set the sticky flag everytime) is to set the maximum limit of SQL Result Tabs to 1 in the Global New Session Properties.

You'll find it here: File --> New Session Properties --> SQL Tab

Comment: Has this option moved somewhere else?

Comment: Just checked, it's still there in V. 3.9.0, right below "SQL result loading".

Answer (score 2):

Right click on a result tab and select sticky. This prevents new result tabs from opening.